# How to get true anomaly using subsatellite point (latitude)?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I am working on an application which is using an orbit propagator. I have a satellite which sets its latitude using this orbit propagator. I want to change the latitude of the satellite by a new value, and to do that and maintain a correct simulation I need to update the true anomaly value.

If I have all the orbit parameters (except the true anomaly) and the new satellite latitude (or orbit angle), how can I get the corresponding True Anomaly?

Regards!

Comment: Do you mean geodetic latitude or spherical coordinates latitude? Do you also have the longitude?

Comment: yeah, geodetic latitude. I also have the longitude